# Difference in defining a variable

Tags: netlogo

I would like to define a new object, and I do not know what could be the best approach.
I know that `let` is used for local variables and this should be the main difference.
I am creating a list in NetLogo that stores elements with some attributes/properties. Since later I will need to pick one of this item up from the list created, what I would need to understand if I need to create the object as a `local` variable or a `global`(`turtle’s own`) variable to do this. 
The two possible cases should be:

1) Create object as a global variable:

```
globals [object
         attribute] 
turtles-own[
    my-list]

to setup 
create-turtles 5
ask turtles [
set my-list []
]
end

to-go

ask one-of turtles[
set attribute 5
set my-list lput object my-list]
end
```

2) Create object as a local variable:

```
turtles-own[
my-list]

to setup 
create-turtles 5
ask turtles [
set my-list []
]
end

to-go

ask one-of turtles[
let object “New object”
let attribute 5 ; this should be assigned to object
set my-list lput object my-list]
end`
```

There should be also another case, i.e. object and attribute defined in turtles-own (this is the case that I would prefer):

```
turtles-own[
object 
attribute 
my-list]

to setup 
create-turtles 5
ask turtles [
set my-list []
]
end

to-go

ask one-of turtles[
set object “New object”
set attribute 5 ; this should be assigned to object
set my-list lput object my-list]
end
```

What I would need to implement is the following:

1. Turtles who have objects stored in a list
2. Objects who have attributes (or also you can interpret it as turtles that create objects with attributes)
3. Turtles that can choose to pick an object up from that list depending on the attribute. (This is the most important point as I need to work with the object and its attributes later).

Could you please help me to understand how I need to implement it?

I would like to avoid hatch or create a breed for object because I am not sure to be able to manage it throughout the code.
However, if this is the only right way to proceed, I will do it.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Val, I realize you initially asked "I would like to ask you the difference in using let and set." but later you explain what you need implemented, which is what I answered.   So, the title of this question is not very accurate.

I'm not sure this is the only way to proceed but I tried to solve your problem, as I understand it, using two breeds ( people and objects ). I hope you can see from the code below how to do that -- just don't use "ask-turtles" anywhere unless you want to affect both people and objects.

Of course post questions here if you run into problems.

Working code is below.

The way I interpreted your question,

- objects are persistent and global,
- changes to an object's attributes by anyone at any time  will update
  the value of that attribute for that object in every agent's my-list
- each person has their own my-list of objects, possibly empty.
- the my-lists of different agents will be different
- each person might search for one of the objects from their list, based on the attribute, and I stored the resulting object, if any, in their current-choice.
- each person should be able to select any of the objects and add that object
  to their my-list

**Implementation design choices:**

- Use two breeds,  "people" and "objects" which own different variables.
- Each object owns an attribute and an object-type ( such as "apple" or "orange")
- Each person owns a my-list and current-choice.    my-list is a list, and
  current-choice is an agent ( possibly = **nobody** )

**Features of the code below**

- The code creates 5 people and 6 objects for testing purposes.  All of them are just left sitting at the origin on the display.
- At each iteration of the "go" step, a random person selects two random objects and adds them to their my-list,  and then locates one of them based on an attribute value.
- the code makes a list of **all** objects in my-list that have the desired attribute,
  which may have zero, one, or more objects in it, and does something sensible based on 
  the length of the list.
- no items are ever removed from my-list, or checked to see if they are already there.
- that's all this does. run setup, run go (once), and inspect the results.

I hope this is helpful.  Let me know here if I didn't answer your question.

Wade

```
;; this is the second version of the code. It has some comments removed or
;; corrected, and initializes current-choice to nobody instead of []

globals [found?]      ;; keep track of whether we found an object  

breed [objects object]
breed [people person]


objects-own [
  object-type      ;  say "apple" or "orange" or "widget"
  attribute        ;  user defined, apparently an integer
]

people-own[
current-choice    ; an agent  
  my-list]        ; a list of objects 


to setup 
  clear-all
  make-people
  make-objects
  reset-ticks
end

to go

  ;; for debugging we'll push two objects onto the my-list for a random agent
  ;; then find one of them with the right attributes and pull it into current-choice

ask one-of people[
    ;; select a random apple, set its attribute to 111, 
    ;; and push it onto this turtle's my-list  

    set current-choice one-of objects with [object-type = "apple"]   
    ask current-choice [set attribute 111 ]              
    set my-list ( lput  current-choice my-list )    

    ;; select a random orange, set its attribute to 222, 
    ;; and push it onto this turtle's mylist  

    set current-choice one-of objects with [object-type = "orange"]    
    ask current-choice [set attribute 222 ]               
    set my-list ( lput  current-choice my-list )     

    ;; ok, let's see if we can find an object in my-list with attribute 111

    let want-attribute 111    ;; for debugging purposes


    ;; make a list of ALL objects on the list with the desired attribute
    ;; as far as we know,there may be many, one, or zero objects with this attribute

    let found-list filter   [ i -> want-attribute =[attribute] of i ]   my-list


    if-else length found-list > 0     
    [ ;; we found at least one match
      set found? true

      ;;  pick a random object from the list of objects which have the desired attribute

      set current-choice one-of found-list
    ]
    [ ;; we didn't find any matches
       set current-choice nobody
       set found? false
      ;; do whatever you do when there is no matching object
    ]

     ;; if desired, check out how things ended up by uncommenting the next
     ;; two lines:
     ;;  inspect current-choice  
     ;;  inspect self

   ]
tick  ;; update the tick counter
end

to make-people
  create-people 5    
   [
    set current-choice nobody
    set my-list []
] 
end

to make-objects
create-objects 3    ; create 3 apples
  [ set object-type "apple"
    set attribute 333 ]

 create-objects 3    ; create 3 oranges
  [ set object-type "orange"
    set attribute 555 ]
end

;; Above code was created by Wade Schuette,  3-November-2019
;; modified sightly 4-November-2019
;; No copyright is claimed.  Enjoy!
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer and for your example! I really appreciated the time that you spent to help me. I have a question, if I may: if I want to plot attribute, how could I do using current-choice? I am working with three different breeds, so I would need to distinguish attribute of `breed1`, attribute of `breed 2`, and attribute of `breed3`. For example, previously I have written: `ask sellers1 [plotxy attribute function1], ask sellers2 [plotxy attribute function2], ask sellers3 [plotxy attribute function3]`. function1,2 and 3 depend on the attribute.

Comment: I created a new post to ask for the error that I received after implementing what you suggested.